# Criar todos os caminhos possíveis de uma matriz bidimensional em Python

Tags: python

Eu tentado de todas forma criar todos os caminhos possíveis de elementos de uma matriz. Como no exemplo abaixo de uma matriz onde eu teria 8 possibilidades totais.

```
[1][0, 1][0, 1]
[1][1][0, 1]
[2][1][0]
[2][2][1]
```

Onde têm mais de um elemento eu gostaria de deixar só um, fazendo todas as combinações possíveis desses elementos como por exemplo

```
[1][0][0] [1][1][1]   [1][0][1]   [1][1][0]
[1][1][0] [1][1][1]   [1][1][0]   [1][1][1]
[2][1][0] [2][1][0]   [2][1][0]   [2][1][0]
[2][2][1] [2][2][1]   [2][2][1]   [2][2][1]
```

E assim por diante até ter todas a possibilidades, em alguns estudos notei uma similaridade com uma ADT chamada de grafos, mas não conseguir implementar muito bem.
Por favor Ajudem, desde já obrigado.